# Effect of the high impedance or low impedance of oscillospe

Tags: oscilloscope

I am measuring a sine waveform range 0 to 40MHz by using Agilent InfiniVision DS0-X 3034A. The data sheet of the oscilloscope is here: http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5990-6619EN.pdf

My question is when do we need to use low or high impedance setting of oscilloscope and why?  I know that high impedance will give less distortion on the waveform, but why it will give less distortion?

Comment: Neither the circuit that you are measuring, nor the circuit you use to measure (the probe/scope combo) are ideal. You need to treat them as real circuits, and analyze as such. The answer then naturally falls out of such analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your point "I know high impedance give less distortion on the waveform" is not true. The high impedance mode adds a lot of capacitance to your circuit at the point of probing, and this excess capacitance certainly can and will distort your circuit, especially at high frequencies.  You will need to consider this when deciding to use one input impedance or the other.

In general, you will almost always want to use the high impedance mode of the scope, i.e. the \$1\mathrm{M} \Omega\$ input impedance when probing a circuit.  You will  use the \$50 \Omega\$ mode if you are connecting to an equivalent \$50 \Omega\$ ohm output impedance of a source, for example a signal generator with a \$50 \Omega\$ output or an RF signal generator with \$50 \Omega\$ characteristic output impedance, or a TX device under test that has a \$50 \Omega\$ output impedance. All transmitters operating in the GHz range will be \$50 \Omega\$ outputs.

When using the \$50 \Omega\$ low impedance input mode, you will want to use a \$50 \Omega\$ coax too. You always want your source, line and load (the oscilloscope input) to be impedance matched to minimize reflections that will add or subtract from the true signal you are measuring.

Most work with high-frequency will want to use the lower impedance, lower capacitance mode with a matched impedance signal chain.

For very high frequency work, there are also so called Lo-Z (low impedance) probes that are nothing more than a short section of \$50 \Omega\$ high quality coax and a series resistor of 450 ohms, giving a x10 probe at \$50 \Omega\$.  This type of probe input is used at very high frequencies, 1GHz or more with up to 10GHz bandwidth. The benefit of this type of \$50 \Omega\$ probe is that it has almost negligible capacitive loading of the device under test, compared to the \$1\mathrm{M} \Omega\$ which has between \$10\$pf-\$20\$pF of capacitance (up to \$100\$pf when you add the length of coax).

A Lo-Z probe such as this adds a \$500 \Omega\$ load to the point where you attach the probe , so you need to be aware of the effect of that load on your circuit at that point.

You always need to be aware of the impedance of your probe and the capacitive load that your probe places on the circuit where you attach it, and can your circuit handle it without causing loading problems and distortion. Only then will you be an oscilloscope Jedi.

Comment: thanks for replied..how do I measure the impedance for my probe?
and for the oscillospe I used,the data sheet didnt display any input impedance value,so how do I determine it?

Comment: your standard x\$1\$ or x\$10\$ probe would be used with the \$1\mathrm{M} \Omega\$ input impedance, so the probe impedance would be \$1\mathrm{M} \Omega\$ ohm in x\$1\$ mode and \$10\mathrm{M} \Omega\$ ohm in x\$10\$ mode. Since  you have the \$3034\$A, a \$350\$Mhz scope, you will have the N\$2890\$A probes, which are \$500\$MHz bandwidth probes.  You would use those with the \$1\mathrm{M} \Omega\$ input impedance. You would certainly have no problem measuring up to \$40\$MHz with this scope and those probes. One more note.. I almost always use x10 mode because it loads the circuit less.

Comment: and for this oscillospe, the input impedance always in 1MΩ for 1x probe? as the oscilloscope didnt have any button for me to change to low impedance. and one more thing, erm, oscillope have impedance, and probe also have impedance, for example,the probe x1 have 1MΩ and oscilloscope have 1MΩ,therefore total input impedance wil be 2MΩ?

Comment: Actually, the \$1\$M\$\Omega\$ probe taken alone, by itself has no impedance (not actually true, it probably has about \$300\Omega\$ in the cable itself)... however, the \$1\$M\$\Omega\$ is not from the probe, it's from the scope. The x\$10\$ mode adds \$9\$M\$\Omega\$ and when added to the \$1\$M\$\Omega\$ in the scope it is \$10\$M\$\Omega\$. For  \$40\$MHz you will want to always use the x\$10\$ mode of the probe because the x\$1\$ mode will be lossy (due to the \$300\Omega\$ in the coax) and probably has less than \$20\$MHz bandwidth because of that: total cap=30pf, R=300, \$1/(2\pi RC)\$

Comment: I just took a look at the datasheet for the N\$2890\$A probes that come with that scope. They are x\$10\$ probes only, they are not switchable, so everything I said about the x\$1\$ probe above, although still true, doesn't apply to your case. You have x\$10\$ probes only, and that is what you want to use anyways.

Comment: @user37970 You might want to check out [W2AEW's video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SX4HGNWBe5M) discussing the difference between x1 and x10 probes. It helps explain impedance matching as well.

Comment: @BrianOnn,as you said earlier,for high frequency, it should use low impedance probe right? but why you always use 10x mode ,isn't 10x mode give high impedance?as x10 =10 ohm, whereas x1 =1ohm.?